# c# Convert a string to 2 doubles

Tags: c#, string, class, split, double

I'm still rather new to the c# programming, so I was trying to make a class method.
But it won't work.

So what do I want to do:
I get some string that has in the name a var. x and y number.
The string for example will be like this: "x02y42"

So I want to have a function inside my application (wpf window) where I can send that string back, and get 2 doubles returned like: "double = 02"  and "double = 42"  (so not as strings).

So I made a new class, 
and within this class I have made this code:

```
public double x,y(string parm)
{
    //input shall be: string s = x12y04;
    //inp s looks like x12y04

    //splut the string on the Y (so this tech should also work for x89232y329)
    //so this will create res[0] that is x89232 and an res[1] that is 329
    string[] res = parm.Split(new string[] { "y" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    //now for the x in res[0], we replace it for a 0 so it are all numbers
    string resx = res[0].Replace("x", "0");

    //now we will get the strings to doubles so we can really start using them.
    double x = double.Parse(resx);
    double y = double.Parse(res[1]);

    //get the values back
    return x, y;

}
```

Now (ofc) it did not work.
But as stated above, I am still pretty new to c#.
So what am I doing wrong here?
I can put this in 1 function right?
So that within my application I can call it somehow?

Comment: this method cannot even be compile... sintax is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to return an array containing the two values. E.g:

```
public double[] Convert(string parm)
{
    //input shall be: string s = x12y04;
    //inp s looks like x12y04

    //splut the string on the Y (so this tech should also work for x89232y329)
    //so this will create res[0] that is x89232 and an res[1] that is 329
    string[] res = parm.Split(new string[] { "y" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    //now for the x in res[0], we replace it for a 0 so it are all numbers
    string resx = res[0].Replace("x", "0");

    //now we will get the strings to doubles so we can really start using them.
    double x = double.Parse(resx);
    double y = double.Parse(res[1]);

    //get the values back
    return new double[] { x, y };

}
```

Comment: Or instead of returning an array you could either return an object that has two properties or use two output parameters.

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for. as a new programmer in C# im still need to understand sometimes, in what cases stuff works. but now that i see this, it makes also sense what i did wong at start. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You must have a background in Python, I can deduce from your code.

In C# prior to 4.0, it is not possible to return multiple values (a tuple) in the *pythonic* way. You need to return an array or return values through `out` arguments. (unless you define your class representing a tuple).

In C# 4.0, you can return a `Tuple<double, double>` as stated in comments.

Comment: That is not true.  He could return Tuple<double, double>.

Comment: Or he could return an instance of `Tuple`, if he is in C# 4 : `return Tuple.Create(x, y);`

Comment: @MattGreer or he could return a descriptive, new class ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use tuples, use F# rather than C#.  In C#, you would have to use some type that represents the tuple; this could be a `Point` type or a `Tuple<,>` type.

Change

```
public double x,y(string parm) 
...
return x, y;
```

to

```
public Point GetXY(string parm) 
...
return new Point(x, y);
```

or

```
public Tuple<double, double> GetXY(string parm) 
...
return Tuple.Create(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot return 2 object from a method

you should return an array of double or a tuple or a point (i think you are using coordinates)

anyway instead of string.split it is preferable to use indexof("x") and "y" and then substring so you can check the passed string and avoid indexoutofrange exception

```
    public double[] GetCoordinates(string inputValue)
    {
        string normalized = inputValue.ToLower();
        int indexX = normalized.IndexOf("x")+1;
        int indexY = normalized.IndexOf("y")+1;

        if (indexX == 0 || indexY == 0) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        //if string is y45x22 i reverse them
        if (indexX > indexY) 
        {
            indexX ^= indexY;
            indexY ^= indexX;
            indexX ^= indexY;
        }
        string xstring = normalized.Substring(indexX, normalized.Length - indexY);
        string ystring = normalized.Substring(indexY, normalized.Length - indexY);

        double[] rtn = new double[2];

        if (!double.TryParse(xstring, out rtn[0]) || !double.TryParse(ystring, out rtn[1])) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        return rtn;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Point
    {
        public Point(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
        public double x { get; set; }
        public double y { get; set; }
    }

public Point ParseString(string parm)
{
    //input shall be: string s = x12y04;
    //inp s looks like x12y04

    //splut the string on the Y (so this tech should also work for x89232y329)
    //so this will create res[0] that is x89232 and an res[1] that is 329
    string[] res = parm.Split(new string[] { "y" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    //now for the x in res[0], we replace it for a 0 so it are all numbers
    string resx = res[0].Replace("x", "0");

    //now we will get the strings to doubles so we can really start using them.
    double x = double.Parse(resx);
    double y = double.Parse(res[1]);

    //get the values back
    return new Point(x,y);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified the code a bit:

```
// C# method names cannot contain character ,
public double[] Parse(string param)
{
    string[] res = param.Split(new string[] { "x",  "y" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    double x = double.Parse(res[0]);
    double y = double.Parse(res[1]);

    //get the values back as array
    return new double[] { x, y };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do...

```
    static Tuple<Double, Double> ParseCoordinates(string parm)
    {
        string[] res = parm.Replace("x","")
                           .Replace("y",",")
                           .Split(",".ToCharArray());
        double x, y;
        double.TryParse(res[0], out x);
        double.TryParse(res[1], out y);

        return new Tuple<double, double>(x, y);

    }
```

if you don't have access to c#4...

```
    static bool ParseCoordinates(string parm, out double x, out double y)
    {
        string[] res = parm.Replace("x","")
                           .Replace("y",",")
                           .Split(",".ToCharArray());

        bool parseX = double.TryParse(res[0], out x);
        bool parseY = double.TryParse(res[1], out y);

        return parseX && parseY;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pair class like below-

```
    public class Pair<T, U> {
      public Pair() {
      }

      public Pair(T first, U second) {
        this.First = first;
        this.Second = second;
      }

     public T First { get; set; }
     public U Second { get; set; }
    };
```

and make return type to a pair object in your method and return 
        new Pair(x, y);

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "x,y" is not a valid method name. Secondly, a method can only return one thing. The key would be to return an object that represent both of your values. Something like a System.Drawing.Point() or a Tuple().

Here's something that should work for you:

```
    public Tuple<double, double> GetXY(string parm)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"x(?<x>\d+)y(?<y>\d+)");

        Match match = regex.Match(parm);
        if (!match.Success)
            return new Tuple<double, double>(0, 0);

        double x, y;
        double.TryParse(match.Groups["x"].Value, out x);
        double.TryParse(match.Groups["y"].Value, out y);

        return new Tuple<double, double>(x, y);
    }
```

You can test it by doing something like:

```
        Console.WriteLine(GetXY("x53y2384"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use output parameters if you really want to have this type of style. However, I agree with the majority of the other posters in that your x/y data should be returned as a separate class that holds the x and y data.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double x, y;

        parse("x12y04", out x, out y);

        //x and y now contain 12 and 4
    }

    static void parse(String parm, out double x, out double y)
    {
        string[] res = parm.Split(new string[] { "y" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string resx = res[0].Replace("x", "0");

        x = double.Parse(resx);
        y = double.Parse(res[1]);
    }
```